# Having trouble with a resizing function

Tags: java, arrays, resize, heap-memory

I am writing a resizing function for a lab and I keep getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
private E[] a, b;  // holds the items
private int N;       // number of items in stack

// create an empty stack with given capacity
public RArrayStack() {
    a = (E[]) new Object[8];
    N = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return N == a.length;
}

public void push(E item) {
    if (!this.isFull()) {
        a[N++] = item;

    } else {
        this.resize();
    }
}

public E pop() {
    return a[--N];
}

public E peek() {
    return a[N - 1];
}

public E[] resize(){
        b = (E[]) new Object[a.length*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i];
        }
        a = b;

    return resize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `resize()` function:

```
public E[] resize(){
        b = (E[]) new Object[a.length*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i];
        }
        a = b;

    return resize();
}
```

You are unconditionally calling `resize()` in the return, which means that the method will recurse until you run out of memory trying to allocate enough memory for the new `b`. Instead of `return resize()`, you want to return `a`